# Flutter: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' when parsing json from hosting

Tags: flutter

I'm parsing json from server and display it on screen. That is work when i parsing from localhost, but when i parsing from hosting there is an error like this

```
I/flutter (18089): [{"id":10,"reservation":"497538","order":"900000025301","equipment":"F6U-EA112","matcode":"6166357","description":"GASKET:2JKT;HE2;1302X1342X3MM;NASB\/CS","q_need":"1","q_available":"0","q_debt":"0","unit":"EA","location":"","required_date":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{"id":11,"reservation":"497538","order":"900000025301","equipment":"F6U-EA112","matcode":"6166345","description":"GASKET:2JKT;HE1;1302X1342X3MM;NASB\/CS","q_need":"1","q_available":"1","q_debt":"0","unit":"EA","location":"GD AUTOMOTIVE","required_date":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{"id":27,"reservation":"497566","order":"900000025329","equipment":"F6U-FA112","matcode":"6166298","description":"GASKET,SPW:IOR;24IN;150LB;GR;304\/304\/CS","q_need":"1","q_available":"0","q_debt":"0","unit":"EA","location":"GD AUTOMOTIVE","required_date":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}]
E/flutter (18089): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(717)] Isolate (398792005) 'main.dart:_spawn()' exited with an error
E/flutter (18089): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (18089): type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'
E/flutter (18089): #0      new Matl.fromJson (package:tams/model/material.dart:49:26)
E/flutter (18089): #1      parseMatl.<anonymous closure> (package:tams/services/material.dart:22:42)
E/flutter (18089): #2      MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:414:29)
E/flutter (18089): #3      ListIterable.toList (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:219:19)
E/flutter (18089): #4      parseMatl (package:tams/services/material.dart:22:58)
E/flutter (18089): #5      _IsolateConfiguration.apply (package:flutter/src/foundation/isolates.dart:88:16)
E/flutter (18089): #6      _spawn.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/isolates.dart:96:30)
E/flutter (18089): #7      Timeline.timeSync (dart:developer/timeline.dart:168:22)
E/flutter (18089): #8      _spawn (package:flutter/src/foundation/isolates.dart:93:12)
E/flutter (18089): #9      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:292:17)
E/flutter (18089): #10     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it.
it because there is different json response from localhost and shared host

**localhost**

```
[{"id":10,"reservation":497538,"order":900000025301,"equipment":"F6U-EA112","matcode":6166357,"description":"GASKET:2JKT;HE2;1302X1342X3MM;NASB\/CS","q_need":1,"q_available":0,"q_debt":0,"unit":"EA","location":"","required_date":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{"id":11,"reservation":497538,"order":900000025301,"equipment":"F6U-EA112","matcode":6166345,"description":"GASKET:2JKT;HE1;1302X1342X3MM;NASB\/CS","q_need":1,"q_available":1,"q_debt":0,"unit":"EA","location":"GD AUTOMOTIVE","required_date":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{"id":27,"reservation":497566,"order":900000025329,"equipment":"F6U-FA112","matcode":6166298,"description":"GASKET,SPW:IOR;24IN;150LB;GR;304\/304\/CS","q_need":1,"q_available":0,"q_debt":0,"unit":"EA","location":"GD AUTOMOTIVE","required_date":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}]
```

**shared host**

```
[{"id":10,"reservation":"497538","order":"900000025301","equipment":"F6U-EA112","matcode":"6166357","description":"GASKET:2JKT;HE2;1302X1342X3MM;NASB\/CS","q_need":"1","q_available":"0","q_debt":"0","unit":"EA","location":"","required_date":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{"id":11,"reservation":"497538","order":"900000025301","equipment":"F6U-EA112","matcode":"6166345","description":"GASKET:2JKT;HE1;1302X1342X3MM;NASB\/CS","q_need":"1","q_available":"1","q_debt":"0","unit":"EA","location":"GD AUTOMOTIVE","required_date":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{"id":27,"reservation":"497566","order":"900000025329","equipment":"F6U-FA112","matcode":"6166298","description":"GASKET,SPW:IOR;24IN;150LB;GR;304\/304\/CS","q_need":"1","q_available":"0","q_debt":"0","unit":"EA","location":"GD AUTOMOTIVE","required_date":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}]
```

Comment: and the solution is here https://serverfault.com/questions/852379/mariadb-reading-integers-as-strings